# Emoji and browsers with WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, unicode, emoji

I am curretly creating a simple website. In the contact information section, I am adding this html entry `&#9742;` for phone (right before the phone number), and this html entry `&#9993;` for email address (right before the email address). The idea is to display those two characters as solid black characters (or any color for that matter if I choose to change the font color in CSS).

Anyway, what I ended up with is the emoji character represented by those two codes. I do not want this. I do not want the emoji representation to be displayed. I would like to see html representation as shown in the following two links:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/260e/index.htm

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2709/index.htm

(in the two links above, notice the 'phone' and the 'envolope' at the top of the page, this is what I want).

The font I am using is 'Lucida Console', and it is part of developing a theme in WordPress.

How can I do this?

---

### Update

This seems to be a problem with WordPress. My html is part of a WordPress theme. When I try the solution with standalone web-pages, it works. However, when I try it within a theme set of files, only emoji is displayed.

So the question now becomes, how do I ensure this works in WordPress properly?

---

### Update 2

It is suggested that this is question is a duplicate of [Inconsistent Unicode Emoji Glyphs/Symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659949/inconsistent-unicode-emoji-glyphs-symbols)

This is not a duplicate question. Just because they both deal with emoji, does not make them both duplicates. My question deals with emoji showing up in a web page when using a WordPress theme, the other question deals with inconsisten emoji characters in mobile devices.

Comment: which font are you using?

Comment: Are you directly edditting the HTML themselves? Some WYSIWYG editors will escape the & character so it will display. One simple option is to just copy and paste it: ☎.

Comment: It seems that Lucida Console doesn't have those characters in their character set, you have to define a fallback font which does have it to avoid the default system one

Comment: @stevenw00 - I am writing directly in the html file. It is part of the footer section for the website. Saved using eclipse.

Comment: hu? you mean that you actually see `&#9742;` instead of ☎ ?

Comment: @Kaiido - No, I see the emoji representation. In the case of a phone, it is a red phone, just like it is shown here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/260e/index.htm (look for the emoji section)

Comment: Yes because it falls back to `Apple Color Emoji`or so if you're on another os, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccL9uw3b/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inconsistent Unicode Emoji Glyphs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659949/inconsistent-unicode-astrological-symbols-on-ios-osx)

Comment: @一二三  This is not a duplicate. The other question you are referring deals with mobile devices. I am dealing with web browsers and WordPress theme

Comment: @Greeso The device makes no difference. The reason for the different visual style is that you didn't specify a "text style" vs. "emoji style" variation selector, and so you got the default for whatever font you were using.

Answer (score 1):

You should include a webfont with support for the characters you want to use.

To include an icon font in your CSS, use the following code :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src:url('fonts/myfont.eot?-td2xif');
    src:url('fonts/myfont.eot?#iefix-td2xif') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/myfont.woff?-td2xif') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/myfont.ttf?-td2xif') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/myfont.svg?-td2xif#myfont') format('svg');
    // Different URLs are required for optimal browser support
    // Make sure to :
    // 1) replace the URLs with your font's URLs
    // 2) replace `#myfont` with the name of your font
    font-weight: normal; // To avoid the font inherits boldness
    font-style: normal; // To avoid font inherits obliqueness or italic
}

.emoji {
    font-family: 'myfont', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; // Use regular fonts as fallback
    speak: none; // To avoid screen readers trying to read the content
    font-style: normal; // To avoid font inherits obliqueness or italic
    font-weight: normal; // To avoid the font inherits boldness
    font-variant: normal; // To avoid the font inherits small-caps
    text-transform: none; // To avoid the font inherits capitalization/uppercase/lowercase
    line-height: 1; // To avoid the font inherits an undesired line-height
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; // For improved readability on Webkit
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; // For improved readability on OSX + Mozilla
}
```

You can then include your symbol like this:

```
<span class="icon">&#9742;</span>
<span class="icon">&#9993;</span>
```

If you don't know a webfont that supports your character, you can easily create one yourself using the [**Icomoon App**](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select). See also my open source [**Emoji icon font**](https://github.com/jslegers/emoji-icon-font) for an example of an Icon font with support for Emoji characters, which I created with the Icomoon App.

---

More info:

- [**Create webfont with Unicode Supplementary Multilingual Plane
  symbols**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824628/create-webfont-with-unicode-supplementary-multilingual-plane-symbols/27410391#27410391)

Comment: I probably misread your suggested answer, but it looks like it is trying to display the emoji character. However I do NOT want the emoji character. It is being displayed for me. I want the non-emoji charachter.

Comment: @Greeso : The code provided will display whatever symbol you assign to &#9742; or &#9993; in the color you set for your font. So if your font uses the color black, it will display the symbol assigned to &#9742; or &#9993; in the color black. This could be a "phone" and "email" symbol, but it could be any other symbol as well if you customize your font.

Comment: @Greeso : You could try my Emoji icon font if you want. It supports both symbols. You can find a demo @ http://jslegers.github.io/emoji-icon-font/. If you decide to use it, however, I would recommend that you edit the font in the Icomoon app to remove all symbols except the ones you need, as that would reduce your filesize significantly!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong this is what you want

```css
#phone{
    font-family:Lucida Console;
    font-size:32px;
    color:red;
}
#email{
    font-family:Lucida Console;
    color:#e3e3e3;
    font-size:30px;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="phone">PHONE &#9742;</div>
<div id="email">EMAIL &#9993;</div>
```

Comment: Except that Lucida Console doesn't have those characters in its character set so your code won't do anything

Comment: Not working :(  Is it because I am using wordpress? I will create a simple webpage that is non-wordpress and see how ti goes.

Comment: Try using font awesome. or give inline color using style attribute

Comment: Example : <div style="font-size:32px;color:red;font-family:Lucida Console;">PHONE &#9742;</div>

I Hope it will surely work in wordpress

Comment: The CSS works, however the problem seems to be WordPress. I did a standalone test, and it looks like it is workig. However, when used with WordPress, only emoji is used.

Answer (score 0):

To force the font renderer to use the non-emoji version, you can try using a Variation Selector.

```html
<div>PHONE EMOJI &#9742;&#65039;</div>
<div>EMAIL EMOJI &#9993;&#65039;</div>

<div>PHONE TEXT &#9742;&#65038;</div>
<div>EMAIL TEXT &#9993;&#65038;</div>
```

See more: http://unicode.org/Public/8.0.0/ucd/StandardizedVariants.html